# How to interrupt AsyncTaskLoader's background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-loader, asynctaskloader

Is there some way to interrupt `AsyncTaskLoader`'s `loadInBackground()` thread when I call `cancelLoad()`? I believe that `AsyncTask.cancel()` does this but the task variables are private and cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stopLoading()` or `abandon()` or `reset()` for that

Article: https://plus.google.com/117981280628062796190/posts/8b9RmQvxudb

[image: Loader States Diagram]

Comment: it doesn't say for any of them that it will interrupt the thread.

Comment: @androiddeveloper take a look on the diagram, X - its often used for marking "stop/break/shutdown" of the threads.

Comment: Seems I've already checked all available methods (according to what I wrote a long time ago) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794783/878126 . Could you please show a sample that proves that the thread is interrupted and doesn't continue what it's doing , using any of the functions you say that will do it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper prove?! its open source - just navigate into code and check

Comment: I don't understand, but I've tried now all of the functions you've mentioned, again, and they still do not interrupt the thread of the loader, just as I wrote 4 years ago. They are not supposed to do it, and it's not even written on the docs you've shown description of. I've updated my answer to include a working sample of how it's possible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the available methods, and it seems none really interrupts the thread that runs in the background.

Looking at the code, it seems that AsyncTask is being used under the hood. I've tried finding a "hole" that I could use to interrupt the asyncTask, but I couldn't find (unless you are fine with reflection).
I think you could make your own loader that will have this functionality.

I think you can modify the code to your needs. Maybe add "forceCancel", which will check the value of the asyncTask, and if it's not null, call "cancel(true)" on it.  Here's the code I've looked at:

**AsyncTaskLoader.java**

```
package android.support.v4.content;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.util.TimeUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

/**
 * Static library support version of the framework's {@link android.content.AsyncTaskLoader}.
 * Used to write apps that run on platforms prior to Android 3.0.  When running
 * on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still used; it does not try
 * to switch to the framework's implementation.  See the framework SDK
 * documentation for a class overview.
 */
public abstract class AsyncTaskLoader<D> extends Loader<D> {
    static final String TAG = "AsyncTaskLoader";
    static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    final class LoadTask extends ModernAsyncTask<Void, Void, D> implements Runnable {

        D result;
        boolean waiting;

        private CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);

        /* Runs on a worker thread */
        @Override
        protected D doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, this + " >>> doInBackground");
            result = AsyncTaskLoader.this.onLoadInBackground();
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, this + "  <<< doInBackground");
            return result;
        }

        /* Runs on the UI thread */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(D data) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, this + " onPostExecute");
            try {
                AsyncTaskLoader.this.dispatchOnLoadComplete(this, data);
            } finally {
                done.countDown();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, this + " onCancelled");
            try {
                AsyncTaskLoader.this.dispatchOnCancelled(this, result);
            } finally {
                done.countDown();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            waiting = false;
            AsyncTaskLoader.this.executePendingTask();
        }
    }

    volatile LoadTask mTask;
    volatile LoadTask mCancellingTask;

    long mUpdateThrottle;
    long mLastLoadCompleteTime = -10000;
    Handler mHandler;

    public AsyncTaskLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Set amount to throttle updates by.  This is the minimum time from
     * when the last {@link #onLoadInBackground()} call has completed until
     * a new load is scheduled.
     *
     * @param delayMS Amount of delay, in milliseconds.
     */
    public void setUpdateThrottle(long delayMS) {
        mUpdateThrottle = delayMS;
        if (delayMS != 0) {
            mHandler = new Handler();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onForceLoad() {
        super.onForceLoad();
        cancelLoad();
        mTask = new LoadTask();
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Preparing load: mTask=" + mTask);
        executePendingTask();
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to cancel the current load task. See {@link android.os.AsyncTask#cancel(boolean)}
     * for more info.  Must be called on the main thread of the process.
     *
     * <p>Cancelling is not an immediate operation, since the load is performed
     * in a background thread.  If there is currently a load in progress, this
     * method requests that the load be cancelled, and notes this is the case;
     * once the background thread has completed its work its remaining state
     * will be cleared.  If another load request comes in during this time,
     * it will be held until the cancelled load is complete.
     *
     * @return Returns <tt>false</tt> if the task could not be cancelled,
     *         typically because it has already completed normally, or
     *         because {@link #startLoading()} hasn't been called; returns
     *         <tt>true</tt> otherwise.
     */
    public boolean cancelLoad() {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "cancelLoad: mTask=" + mTask);
        if (mTask != null) {
            if (mCancellingTask != null) {
                // There was a pending task already waiting for a previous
                // one being canceled; just drop it.
                if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG,
                        "cancelLoad: still waiting for cancelled task; dropping next");
                if (mTask.waiting) {
                    mTask.waiting = false;
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
                }
                mTask = null;
                return false;
            } else if (mTask.waiting) {
                // There is a task, but it is waiting for the time it should
                // execute.  We can just toss it.
                if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "cancelLoad: task is waiting, dropping it");
                mTask.waiting = false;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
                mTask = null;
                return false;
            } else {
                boolean cancelled = mTask.cancel(false);
                if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "cancelLoad: cancelled=" + cancelled);
                if (cancelled) {
                    mCancellingTask = mTask;
                }
                mTask = null;
                return cancelled;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Called if the task was canceled before it was completed.  Gives the class a chance
     * to properly dispose of the result.
     */
    public void onCanceled(D data) {
    }

    void executePendingTask() {
        if (mCancellingTask == null && mTask != null) {
            if (mTask.waiting) {
                mTask.waiting = false;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
            }
            if (mUpdateThrottle > 0) {
                long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                if (now < (mLastLoadCompleteTime+mUpdateThrottle)) {
                    // Not yet time to do another load.
                    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Waiting until "
                            + (mLastLoadCompleteTime+mUpdateThrottle)
                            + " to execute: " + mTask);
                    mTask.waiting = true;
                    mHandler.postAtTime(mTask, mLastLoadCompleteTime+mUpdateThrottle);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Executing: " + mTask);
            mTask.executeOnExecutor(ModernAsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[]) null);
        }
    }

    void dispatchOnCancelled(LoadTask task, D data) {
        onCanceled(data);
        if (mCancellingTask == task) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Cancelled task is now canceled!");
            rollbackContentChanged();
            mLastLoadCompleteTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            mCancellingTask = null;
            executePendingTask();
        }
    }

    void dispatchOnLoadComplete(LoadTask task, D data) {
        if (mTask != task) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Load complete of old task, trying to cancel");
            dispatchOnCancelled(task, data);
        } else {
            if (isAbandoned()) {
                // This cursor has been abandoned; just cancel the new data.
                onCanceled(data);
            } else {
                commitContentChanged();
                mLastLoadCompleteTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                mTask = null;
                if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Delivering result");
                deliverResult(data);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     */
    public abstract D loadInBackground();

    /**
     * Called on a worker thread to perform the actual load. Implementations should not deliver the
     * result directly, but should return them from this method, which will eventually end up
     * calling {@link #deliverResult} on the UI thread. If implementations need to process
     * the results on the UI thread they may override {@link #deliverResult} and do so
     * there.
     *
     * @return Implementations must return the result of their load operation.
     */
    protected D onLoadInBackground() {
        return loadInBackground();
    }

    /**
     * Locks the current thread until the loader completes the current load
     * operation. Returns immediately if there is no load operation running.
     * Should not be called from the UI thread: calling it from the UI
     * thread would cause a deadlock.
     * <p>
     * Use for testing only.  <b>Never</b> call this from a UI thread.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    public void waitForLoader() {
        LoadTask task = mTask;
        if (task != null) {
            try {
                task.done.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dump(String prefix, FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter writer, String[] args) {
        super.dump(prefix, fd, writer, args);
        if (mTask != null) {
            writer.print(prefix); writer.print("mTask="); writer.print(mTask);
                    writer.print(" waiting="); writer.println(mTask.waiting);
        }
        if (mCancellingTask != null) {
            writer.print(prefix); writer.print("mCancellingTask="); writer.print(mCancellingTask);
                    writer.print(" waiting="); writer.println(mCancellingTask.waiting);
        }
        if (mUpdateThrottle != 0) {
            writer.print(prefix); writer.print("mUpdateThrottle=");
                    TimeUtils.formatDuration(mUpdateThrottle, writer);
                    writer.print(" mLastLoadCompleteTime=");
                    TimeUtils.formatDuration(mLastLoadCompleteTime,
                            SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), writer);
                    writer.println();
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: after 3 years, I've decided to post my solution for this:

```
/**
 * makes it a bit easier to use AsyncTaskLoader. based on https://github.com/alexjlockwood/AppListLoader
 */
abstract class AsyncTaskLoaderEx<T>(context: Context) : AsyncTaskLoader<T>(context) {
    @JvmField
    var hasResult = false
    @Suppress("MemberVisibilityCanBePrivate")
    @JvmField
    var isCanceled = false
    var result: T? = null
        private set
    private var _currentThread: Thread? = null

    init {
        onContentChanged()
    }

    override fun onStartLoading() {
        if (takeContentChanged())
            forceLoad()
    }

    override fun deliverResult(data: T?) {
        result = data
        hasResult = true
        super.deliverResult(data)
    }

    override fun onLoadInBackground(): T? {
        _currentThread = Thread.currentThread()
        return super.onLoadInBackground()
    }

    open fun interrupt() {
        isCanceled = true
        _currentThread?.interrupt()
    }

    override fun onReset() {
        super.onReset()
        onStopLoading()
        if (hasResult) {
            onReleaseResources(result)
            result = null
            hasResult = false
        }
    }

    protected open fun onReleaseResources(data: T?) {
        //nothing to do.
    }

    companion object {
        private val sCurrentUniqueId = AtomicInteger(0)
        @JvmStatic
        val newUniqueLoaderId: Int
            get() = sCurrentUniqueId.getAndIncrement()
    }
}
```

And usage sample:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        val TASK_LOADER_ID = AsyncTaskLoaderEx.newUniqueLoaderId
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val loaderManager = LoaderManager.getInstance(this)
        loaderManager.initLoader(TASK_LOADER_ID, null, object : LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Boolean?> {
            override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Boolean?> {
                return ImageLoadingTask(this@MainActivity)
            }

            override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Boolean?>, result: Boolean?) {
                Log.d("AppLog", "finished without being interrupted?:$result")
                if (result == null)
                    return
                //TODO use result

            }

            override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<Boolean?>) {
            }
        })
        val runnable = Runnable {
            Log.d("AppLog", "trying to stop loader")
            (loaderManager.getLoader<Loader<Boolean?>>(TASK_LOADER_ID) as AsyncTaskLoaderEx?)?.interrupt()
        }
        val handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000L)
        Log.d("AppLog", "will try to interrupt in 2 seconds")
        lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {
            @Suppress("unused")
            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
            fun onDestroy() {
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
            }
        })
    }

    private class ImageLoadingTask(context: Context) : AsyncTaskLoaderEx<Boolean?>(context) {

        override fun loadInBackground(): Boolean? {
            try {
                for (i in 0..10) {
                    Log.d("AppLog", "loadInBackground: $i")
                    Thread.sleep(1000L)
                }
                return true
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                Log.d("AppLog", "INTERRUPTED!!!")
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively simple to add that functionality, this is the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ncruces/312a48c86614c8bac897a37365257ddf) of it:

```
public abstract class InterruptibleAsyncTaskLoader<D> extends AsyncTaskLoader<D> {
    private volatile Thread thread;

    public InterruptibleAsyncTaskLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public boolean isLoadInBackgroundRunning() {
        return thread != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelLoadInBackground() {
        Thread t = thread;
        if (t != null) t.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public final D loadInBackground() {
        try {
            thread = Thread.currentThread();
            return doLoadInBackground();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            OperationCanceledException oce = new OperationCanceledException(e.toString());
            oce.initCause(e);
            throw oce;
        } finally {
            Thread.interrupted();
            thread = null;
        }
    }

    public abstract D doLoadInBackground() throws InterruptedException;
}
```