# IllegalStateException when restarting Loader (SQLite) from an AsyncTask inside of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, ormlite, android-loadermanager

I am noticing some `IllegalStateException` crashes in my analytics report that I can't seem to reproduce.  Am I doing something structurally incorrect here? I have included some pseudocode that hopefully shows my fragment's skeleton without being too cluttered.  I don't recall seeing this error until I refactored my code to use fragments.  The error occurs in AsyncTask's `onPostExecute`.  Please let me know if I can better clarify my problem / pseudocode better.

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment 
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    Fragment fragment = this;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    // onActivityCreated initializes the adapter and the loader

    public AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> onCreateloader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CustomCursorLoader(this);
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    private class CustomCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        public CustomCursorLoader(Fragment fragment) {
            // get a handle to the OrmLite database helper class
            databaseHelper = (DatabaseHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(fragment.getActivity(), DatabaseHelper.class);
        }

        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            // construct the Cursor that will be used for loading results from the SQLite database
        }
    }

    private class Task extends AsyncTask {
        // pre execute

        // grab some new database results from the server and repopulate the SQLite database using OrmLite

        public void onPostExecute() {
            fragment.getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I was able to reproduce the issue by initiating the `Task` and then immediately hitting back.  When the `Task` finishes the activity that contains the fragment is not active so the call to `getLoaderManager` fails.  The question now is, what is the most elegant way to handle this?  I suppose I can just catch the Exception.

**Update 2**

I believe I can make use of [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) to prevent `onPostExecute` from executing.  If I do this I will probably need to move `initLoader` to another method than `onActivityCreated` in order to refresh the loader when the user does come back to the page (since the results updated, just not the loader).

**Update 3**

I am wondering, like Robby Pond mentions in the comments, if using a Loader here is overkill?

Comment: Please, post the logcat output (stacktrace) for more info

Comment: @stan0 I wish that I could.  I am using the `EasyTracker` in analytics so all I get is the exception name and line number.  I can't seem to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: When are you creating and executing Task?

Comment: @RobbyPond If there are currently no results in the database then in `onActivityCreated`.  Otherwise, in `onOptionsItemSelected` when they hit the refresh action bar item.

Comment: I don't think we can also with the amount of code. Why are you using both a Loader and an AsyncTask to query the database?

Comment: @RobbyPond I read that is how I should refresh a `ListView` rather than `notifyDataSetChanged`.  At one point I was requerying within the AsyncTask but switched over to Loaders.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error!  It happens if I initiate the `Task` and then immediately hit back.  When The Task completes we are no longer on the activity that contains the fragment so `getLoaderManager` fails.

Comment: @RobbyPond After doing some reading and thinking, I think I see what you mean.  Since I am already doing a network call in `AsyncTask` I can just manipulate the adapter's cursor there, rather than also using a `Loader`.  Would you never need a Loader then if you are refreshing data already in an asynchronous way?

Comment: @RobbyPond I completely gutted the `Loader` and just use `swapCursor` in my `AsyncTask`.  You were correct in suggesting that I shouldn't be using both a `Loader and AsyncTask`.  If you want to put your comment as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Uh, what's the IllegalStateException say?  Any caused-by messages?

Answer (score 0):

Some of my thoughts about your case:

1. Loader has various issues, especially when used with fragments. I could advise you to use ViewModel, but I think they are both based on same code. You could use a normal thread and then use something like EventBus to publish the result, but maybe it's an overkill
2. I can see that you've forgot to set the classes as static, which means they have a reference to the hosting class.
3. Is it possible for you to merge the async code into one AsyncTaskLoader ?
4. You can try my general solution of using AsyncTaskLoader, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675607/878126).
5. Maybe instead of a restart, first destroy and then call initLoader again.
6. AsyncTask should only be used in small cases, where you don't care if the result is gone (example when you change orientation). A good example is for a list of items to show.
7. I think Google mentioned on Google IO 2018 that the issues with Loaders will be fixed. Not sure if in support library 28, or on AndroidX library. I suggest to check it out. The main thing to remember is to use it only on the UI thread.