# Android - Difference between Thread and AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-handler, java-threads

In my app i have buttons, when clicked will query the database and show result on screen. The query action will normally take 1 ~ 3 sec. These buttons will be clicked very often.

I've implemented this action on both AsyncTask and Thread but see very little different.

However in the long term, especially when the buttons are clicked many times, which will be more beneficial, in terms of resources (CPU, memory) ?

Comment: AsyncTaskloader is my guess: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20279805/2413303

Comment: Thanks for your replay EpicPandaForce. I read the link. They said:  "the AsyncTaskLoader can survive through config changes like screen flips". But the query is short, is it necessary to handle the config changes also ?

Comment: @ngubk, it is necessary to handle config changes in almost all cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a `Thread`, you have to update the result on the main thread using the `runOnUiThread()` method, while an `AsyncTask` has the `onPostExecute()` method which automatically executes on the main thread after `doInBackground()` returns.

While there is no significant difference between these two in terms of "which is more beneficial", I think that the `AsyncTask` abstraction was devised so that a programmer doesn't have to synchronize the UI & worker threads. When using a `Thread`, it may not always be as simple as calling `runOnUiThread()`; it can get very tricky very fast. So if I were you, I'd stick to using `AsyncTask` and keep `Thread` for more specialized situations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case, I use handler.sendMessage() in the thread instead of runOnUiThread(), is this good or AsyncTask is still better ?

Comment: My implementation is very similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954611/android-when-should-i-use-a-handler-and-when-should-i-use-a-thread

Comment: I understand ... what I can say is that `AsyncTask` is specifically meant for the case when one of the two threads is the UI / main thread. `Thread` and `Handler` can even be used when neither of the two threads is the UI thread. I hope you understand this difference ... thats why whenever UI is involved, one should preferably use an `AsyncTask` as that is a recognizable idiom :)  ... you can of course continue to use `Thread` and `Handler` as it is equally right too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I ll use the AsyncTask, as it is a good practise

Answer (score 1):

An `AsyncTask` is used to do some background computation and publish the result to the UI thread (with optional progress updates). Since you're not concerned with UI, then a `Handler` or `Thread` seems more appropriate.

Reference : [Handler vs AsyncTask vs Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread)

Comment: not concerned with UI ? He says he has to display the results on the screen.