# How to save fragment state in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, residemenu

I have one HomeActivity from where I am calling the list of fragments. In HomeActivity I have sidemenu where all fragments are loaded.

Now,in this list i have one fragment called HomeFragment which display the Google Map with data, using webservice.

What i want is i want to load the Map dat only once(first time) fragment is loaded, not every time when click on sidemenu or come in from any other fragment.

My HomeFragment or any other fragments are loaded at once, not every time.

Comment: You need to use hide/show fragment transaction instead of detach, remove, replace, etc

Comment: For loading data and saving them even when the activity is re-created, this can be done via a loader (like AsyncTaskLoader). Here's an example of how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22675607/878126

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can hide/show fragment. No need to replace, remove. For ex, I have 2 fragments FragmentFeed and FragmentNotification, we can hide/show or add fragment.

Handle click menu:

```
if (tabId.equals(AppConstants.FEED)) {
                    pushFragments(tabId, getFragmentFeed());
                } else if (tabId.equals(AppConstants.NOTIFICATION)) {
                    pushFragments(tabId, getFragmentNotification());
                }
```

Handle show/hide and  add fragment:

```
public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();


        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
            ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment, tag);
        }

        Fragment fragmentFeed = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FEED);
        Fragment fragmentNoti = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_NOTIFICATION);

        // Hide all Fragment
        if (fragmentFeed != null) {
            ft.hide(fragmentFeed);
        }
        if (fragmentNoti != null) {
            ft.hide(fragmentNoti);
        }

        // Show  current Fragment
        if (tag == TAG_FEED) {
            if (fragmentFeed != null) {
                ft.show(fragmentFeed);
            }
        }
        if (tag == TAG_NOTIFICATION) {
            if (fragmentNoti != null) {
                ft.show(fragmentNoti);
            }
        }



        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @RoShan Shan. It's working for me. It's save my couple of hours.

Comment: Saved my life!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use two things.

First onSavedInstance of your Fragment.
Fill it with the info you want.

Second setRetainState(true). This will prevent your fragment from destroying even if it is detached. Hope this helps.