# Restoring fragment state when changing fragments through bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationbar, bottomnavigationview

I have bottom navigation bar on click of item in navigation bar i am replacing fragments. I have 3 fragments A,B,C so on click of b item B fragment is loaded and in B i am calling 3-4 APIs. So now if i go to C and then again come to B a new instance of B Fragment is created and again those APIs are called how can i save the fragment instance state and not call APIs again while changing fragments. This is my code.

```
mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            Fragment currentLoaded = fgMan.findFragmentById(R.id.container_body);
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.nearby_fragment:
                    if (!(currentLoaded instanceof SpotFeedMapFragment)) {
                        removeScroll();
                        mNearByFragment = fgMan.findFragmentByTag(NEARBY_FRAGMENT_TAG) != null ? fgMan.findFragmentByTag(NEARBY_FRAGMENT_TAG) : mNearByFragment;
                        fgMan.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
                        fgMan.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, mNearByFragment, NEARBY_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
                        fgMan.executePendingTransactions();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.nearby_fragment));
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.route_fragment:
                    if (!(currentLoaded instanceof BusLocationsFragment)) {
                        if (!inParent) {
                            mRl.removeView(fixLayout);
                            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, toolbar.getId());
                            scrollView.setLayoutParams(p);
                            scrollView.addView(fixLayout);
                            mRl.addView(scrollView);
                            inParent = true;
                        }
                        //mFragment = new BusLocationsFragment();
                        mBusLocFragment = fgMan.findFragmentByTag(BUS_LOC_FRAGMENT_TAG) != null ? fgMan.findFragmentByTag(BUS_LOC_FRAGMENT_TAG) : mBusLocFragment;
                        fgMan.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
                        fgMan.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, mBusLocFragment, BUS_LOC_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
                        fgMan.executePendingTransactions();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.newsfeed_activity:
                    if (!(currentLoaded instanceof NewsFeedActivity)) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                            removeScroll();
                        }
                        mNewsFeedFragment = fgMan.findFragmentByTag(NEWSFEED_FRAGMENT_TAG) != null ? fgMan.findFragmentByTag(NEWSFEED_FRAGMENT_TAG) : mNewsFeedFragment;
                        fgMan.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
                        fgMan.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, mNewsFeedFragment, NEWSFEED_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
                        fgMan.executePendingTransactions();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.news));
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I have already initialized fragments member variables above in `onCreate`of `MainActivity`

Comment: just an idea i cant provide code since i dont have the dev tools right now. dont use `.replace` in fragment transaction. this will make the destroy its instance to the backstack. replace it with `.add`. When you click on a button to change for example fragment a to b and then fragment b is already opened before, you can check youre backstack if fragment b is already there and pop it here is a sample http://stackoverflow.com/a/9787891/5870896 . Make sure to add the fragment on backstack everytime you visit it to save its instance

Comment: anyone knows is it better to hide/show fragment transaction instead of detach, remove, replace or add? (like this another answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/42434392/4074312)

Answer (score 15):

You should use a FragmentPagerAdapter to initiate the fragments so when you want to switch in between them, the state of the fragments will be saved.

```
CutomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter (MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new SpotFeedMapFragment(), "title");
adapter.addFragment(new BusLocationsFragment(), "title");
adapter.addFragment(new NewsFeedActivity(), "title");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then in the bottom navigation selected you can set fragment by simple command

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(n);
```

my viewpager class is as follows:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean isPagingEnabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.isPagingEnabled = true;
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.isPagingEnabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

//for samsung phones to prevent tab switching keys to show on keyboard
@Override
public boolean executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    return isPagingEnabled && super.executeKeyEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.isPagingEnabled = enabled;
}
}
```

in the xml instead of a empty layout for fragemnt u need:

```
<com.package.util.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Code for custom FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>> instantiatedFragments = new SparseArray<>();
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        final Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        instantiatedFragments.put(position, new WeakReference<>(fragment));
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        instantiatedFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Nullable
    Fragment getFragment(final int position) {
        final WeakReference<Fragment> wr = instantiatedFragments.get(position);
        if (wr != null) {
            return wr.get();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, simply keep viewpager and it will take care fragment state, then give page limit, finally remove the viewpager swipe.

Comment: `FragmentPagerAdapter` is an abstract class. Code is missing for custom fragment pager adapter class which should extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: @Ranjan It is a simple implementation. However I added my custom FragmentPagerAdapter if you need it.

Answer (score 7):

To restore/retain a fragment's state you should use **ViewPager2** as it is the updated version of *ViewPager*.

You will get the code on [my **GitHub** repository](https://github.com/rawnak-yazdani/android-java-snippet-bottom-navigation-viewpager2) with ***three menu items*** in the **Bottom Navigation Bar** with more functionality. I am also providing a simple description here with ***two menu items*** in the **Bottom Navigation Bar**.

***Step by step guide (to restore/retain an EditText's state as an example):***

**Step 1:**

Add **dependencies** in your **build.gradle** (app module) file:

```
dependencies {

    def nav_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'

}
```

**Step 2:**

Add **menu_bottom_navigation.xml** to **res/menu**: (You may also add **icons** to **menu items**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_first"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="First"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_second"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="Second"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**Step 3:**

Add **activity_main.xml** to **res/layout**: (adding menu to **BottomNavigationView** and placing **ViewPager2**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconSize="20dp"
        android:background="#A8DD44"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 4:**

Add **fragment_first.xml** to **res/layout**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    tools:context="com.example.rough.Fragment.FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Fragment"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write something &amp; it will stay"
        android:ems="13"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 5:**

Add **fragment_second.xml** to **res/layout**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rough.Fragment.SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Fragment"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write something &amp; it will stay"
        android:ems="13"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 6:**

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, Lifecycle b ) {
        super(fragmentManager,b);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

}
```

**Step 7:**

**FirstFragment.java**:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

}
```

**Step 8:**

**SecondFragment.java**:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {


    public SecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }

}
```

**Step 9:**

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;

    FirstFragment firstFragment;
    SecondFragment secondFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager2);
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu_first:
                                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(0,false);
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu_second:
                                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(1,false);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_first).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_second).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        setupViewPager(viewPager2);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager2 viewPager) {

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());

        firstFragment =new FirstFragment();
        secondFragment =new SecondFragment();

        adapter.addFragment(firstFragment);
        adapter.addFragment(secondFragment);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly I was searching for it from the whole day and now final got this awesome explanation! thanks a lot from the depth of my heart

Comment: I implemented viewPager2 on the place of viewPager, only for the purpose of disabling the swiping feature, anybody who want same can use this line to achieve the end results :-  viewpager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);

Comment: it has any performance issue or not if it has 4 to 5 fragments and each fragment contains  large data ?

Answer (score 6):

I used `bottom navigation bar` and I did it by  customizing viewpager and I disable the swipe navigation. Each time user clicks bottom item, set relevant fragment in viewpager. Viewpager control state of fragment, so no need control state.

**Custom ViewPager**

```
public class BottomNavigationViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public BottomNavigationViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Enable or disable the swipe navigation
     * @param enabled
     */
    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

If you still want to control state of fragment, you can see my answer in this link
[How to save fragment state in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434392/how-to-save-fragment-state-in-android/42435596#42435596)

Comment: I believe the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434392/how-to-save-fragment-state-in-android/42435596#42435596) above is the answer that I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Solution Using Navigation Component**

Use these versions, Multi stack support is only available from these versions

```
versions.fragment = "1.4.0-alpha01"
versions.navigation = "2.4.0-alpha01"
```

First, you need to create nav graphs for each fragment in the bottom navigation

Filename: first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/first"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:label="@string/fragment_A_title"
        android:name="com.app.company.HomeFragment"
    >
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

create nav graph for all tabs and setup bottom navigation menu using these ids

```
<item android:title="@string/title_one"
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_24"/>

<item android:title="@string/title_two"
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_24"/>

.
.

.
```

include these nav graphs inside the main nav graph and use this main graph in FragmentContainerView

```
<include app:graph="@navigation/first"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/second"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/third"/>
```

Setup the bottom navigation

```
  val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_host) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController


        val controller = binding.bottonNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)


        appBarConfig = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.homeFragment,
                R.id.secondFragment,
                R.id.thirdFragment
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)
```

Refer to the following link for more info

[Navigation multiple back stacks](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for that is to override "OnCreate()" method in your Fragment B and call you APIs in "OnCreate()" method instead of "OnCreateView()".

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: but oncreateView() will get called always

Comment: That's why we are shifting all our code from OnCreateView to OnCreate()

Comment: @Zohaib...That is Fine, Even check the question once what he is asking?. His question is maintaining state to be specific View state, as far as my understanding is, BottomNavigationView doesn't support it as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to bring ViewPager in to accomplish this. I have one activity with a `BottomNavigationView` and a fragment container. When a user clicks a navigation tab, I do the following:

```
final Fragment existing = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().forEach(transaction::hide);
if (existing != null) {
    transaction.show(existing);
} else {
    transaction.add(R.id.new_main_fragment_frame, instantiate, fragmentName);
}
transaction.commit();
```

I'm handling my own back press at the activity level by overriding `onBackPressed` and this is working well. The fragments lazy load in and then are re-used if the user is switching between tabs.