# How to restore fragment states while using bottom navigation view in android?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to do restoring the fragment view state values(text view,..etc) when back from second fragment in android bottom navigation view.

MyActivity.java

```
public class LandingPage extends AppCompatActivity implements ProductFragment.AddToCart {

    Fragment fragment;
    TextView txtCart;
    Button btnCart;
    ItemData itemData;
    ArrayList<ItemData> itemDataList;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragment = new ProductFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    fragment = new ReportsFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_logout:
                    LogOut();
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page);

        txtCart = findViewById(R.id.txt_cart);
        btnCart = findViewById(R.id.btn_cartImg);

        itemDataList = new ArrayList<>();

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        loadFragment(new ProductFragment());
}
 private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

ProductFragment.java

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    Button btnCart1,btnCart2,btnCart3;
    AddToCart addToCart;
    TextView txtItem1Des,txtItem1Price,txtItem2Des,txtItem2Price,txtItem3Des,txtItem3Price;
    Button btnCart1Inc,btnCart1Dec,btnCart2Inc,btnCart2Dec,btnCart3Inc,btnCart3Dec;
    TextView cart1txt,cart2txt,cart3txt;
    String itemDes,itemPrice,itemImg,itemCount;
    int quantity1,quantity2,quantity3;

    public ProductFragment() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);

        btnCart1 = view.findViewById(R.id.cart1);
        txtItem1Des = view.findViewById(R.id.cart1_desc);
        txtItem1Price = view.findViewById(R.id.cart1_price);
        btnCart1Inc = view.findViewById(R.id.cart1Inc);
        btnCart1Dec = view.findViewById(R.id.cart1Dec);
        cart1txt = view.findViewById(R.id.cart1txt);

        btnCart2 = view.findViewById(R.id.cart2);
        txtItem2Des = view.findViewById(R.id.cart2_desc);
        txtItem2Price = view.findViewById(R.id.cart2_price);
        btnCart2Inc = view.findViewById(R.id.cart2Inc);
        btnCart2Dec = view.findViewById(R.id.cart2Dec);
        cart2txt = view.findViewById(R.id.cart2txt);

        btnCart3 = view.findViewById(R.id.cart3);
        txtItem3Des = view.findViewById(R.id.cart3_desc);
        txtItem3Price = view.findViewById(R.id.cart3_price);
        btnCart3Inc = view.findViewById(R.id.cart3Inc);
        btnCart3Dec = view.findViewById(R.id.cart3Dec);
        cart3txt = view.findViewById(R.id.cart3txt);

        quantity1 = Integer.parseInt(cart1txt.getText().toString());
        quantity2 = Integer.parseInt(cart2txt.getText().toString());
        quantity3 = Integer.parseInt(cart3txt.getText().toString());

        buttonInitialization();
        addingToCart();

        return view;
    }

    private void addingToCart() {
        btnCart1Dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(quantity1 <= 1){
                    btnCart1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnCart1Dec.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnCart1Inc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    cart1txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    addToCart.removeItemFromCart(1);
                }else {
                    quantity1 = quantity1-1;
                    cart1txt.setText(String.valueOf(quantity1));
                    addToCart.itemCount(cart1txt.getText().toString(),"1");
                }

            }
        });
        btnCart1Inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                quantity1 = quantity1+1;
                cart1txt.setText(String.valueOf(quantity1));
                addToCart.itemCount(cart1txt.getText().toString(),"1");
            }
        });
        btnCart2Dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(quantity2 <= 1){
                    btnCart2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnCart2Dec.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnCart2Inc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    cart2txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    addToCart.removeItemFromCart(2);
                }else {
                    quantity2 = quantity2-1;
                    cart2txt.setText(String.valueOf(quantity2));
                    addToCart.itemCount(cart2txt.getText().toString(),"2");
                }

            }
        });
        btnCart2Inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                quantity2 = quantity2+1;
                cart2txt.setText(String.valueOf(quantity2));
                addToCart.itemCount(cart2txt.getText().toString(),"2");
            }
        });
        btnCart3Dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(quantity3 <= 1){
                    btnCart3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnCart3Dec.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnCart3Inc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    cart3txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    addToCart.removeItemFromCart(3);
                }else {
                    quantity3 = quantity3-1;
                    cart3txt.setText(String.valueOf(quantity3));
                    addToCart.itemCount(cart3txt.getText().toString(),"3");
                }

            }
        });
        btnCart3Inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                quantity3 = quantity3+1;
                cart3txt.setText(String.valueOf(quantity3));
                addToCart.itemCount(cart3txt.getText().toString(),"3");
            }
        });
    }


    private void buttonInitialization() {
        btnCart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    itemImg = "";
                    itemPrice = txtItem1Price.getText().toString().trim();
                    itemDes = txtItem1Des.getText().toString().trim();
                    itemCount = cart1txt.getText().toString().trim();
                    addToCart.cartCount("",itemPrice,itemDes,itemCount,"1");
                    btnCart1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnCart1Dec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnCart1Inc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cart1txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        btnCart2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                itemImg = "";
                itemPrice = txtItem2Price.getText().toString().trim();
                itemDes = txtItem2Des.getText().toString().trim();
                itemCount = cart2txt.getText().toString().trim();
                addToCart.cartCount("",itemPrice,itemDes,itemCount,"2");
                btnCart2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnCart2Dec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnCart2Inc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cart2txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        btnCart3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                itemImg = "";
                itemPrice = txtItem3Price.getText().toString().trim();
                itemDes = txtItem3Des.getText().toString().trim();
                itemCount = cart3txt.getText().toString().trim();
                addToCart.cartCount("",itemPrice,itemDes,itemCount,"3");
                btnCart3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnCart3Dec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnCart3Inc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cart3txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        addToCart = (AddToCart) context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
   public interface AddToCart{
        void cartCount(String item_img,String item_price,String item_desc,String item_count,String item_pos);
        void removeItemFromCart(int removeItem);
        void itemCount(String itemCount,String position);
    }

}
```

Here in ProductFragment iam going to add values to text view. When i was coming from ReportFragment the view values are going to be cleared in ProductFragment.

Comment: Instead of replacing fragment, just add it. It will draw over the current one.

Comment: The ReportFragments contains a different views.If we add the fragment. The ProductFragment views are will appear in ReportFragment.

Comment: @amarlucky add fragment to stack while replacing and pop up on Back press

Answer (score 2):

I would consider doing that in two steps:

1. save fragment instance instead of re-creating a new one every time

   ```
   private ProductFragment productFragment;
   private ReportsFragment reportsFragment;

   private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

           switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.nav_home:
                   if(productFragment == null)
                     productFragment = new ProductFragment();
                   loadFragment(productFragment);
                   break;
               case R.id.nav_profile:
                   if(reportsFragment == null)
                     reportsFragment = new ReportsFragment();
                   loadFragment(reportsFragment);
                   break;
               case R.id.nav_logout:
                   LogOut();
                   return true;
           }
           return true;
       }
   };
   ```
2. referring to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505327/android-save-restore-fragment-state), you should implement in your fragment both `void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState)` and `void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

In that way you will surely keep the instance of your fragment instead of creating a new one every time (`new MyFragment()` will always re-create it). In addition, saving your views state in `onSaveInstanceState` and restoring it in your `onActivityCreate`, will allow you to keep your views/values.

I wrote that by hand without a compiler, so it might not be perfect.

let me know if you need further information.

Good luck

Comment: I tried it doesn't work for me. I just used this solution https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711 , its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [this solution](https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711) and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks @faranjit, Your solution working for me.I tried since one day.Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should see [**my detailed answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781409/restoring-fragment-state-when-changing-fragments-through-bottom-navigation-bar/63307225#63307225) to a similar question. I hope it will solve your problem.