# How to save fragment state : Bottom Navigation View with fragments android

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Im creating a app with three sections home,color,profile I'm using bottom navigation view with fragments to achieve this.

[App UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ9RK.png)
Here is my code:
Main Activity on create method:

```
final HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
final ColorFragment colorFragment = new ColorFragment();
final ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment active = homeFragment;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_home:
                        active = homeFragment;
                        break;
                        //return true;
                    case R.id.action_color:
                        active = colorFragment;
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_profile:
                        active = profileFragment;
                        break;
                    default:
                        active = homeFragment;
                        break;
                }
                //Loading the fragment on click
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,active).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Im using fragment manager to load the fragment in my Main Activity which comes with below problem.

1.It reloads the fragment each time I click on the bottom navigation icon.(Im getting data from firebase this will be costly )

I have read many articles regarding this,i found solutions like below:

1. Using hiding the fragments on creation of activity

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, profileFragment, "3").hide(profileFragment).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, colorFragment, "2").hide(colorFragment).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,homeFragment, "1").commit();
```

Above solution loads all the fragments on the creation of activity which isn't a efficient scnario

2. Using NavHost :
   It refresh the fragment every time.

This also not working for me.

Please Help:

What I want to acheive:
1.The fragment should only load when I click on the icon for the first time.
2.All the fragments should not load at the time of activity creation.
3.When I revist the fragment It should not load again, I should stay at previous state ex. scrolled till 25th card

//Its should be like playstore,youtube where when we click on icon it loads the data, when we revisit the state will be there.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use extension function provided by Google for `BottomNavigationView` or use a `ViewPager`/`ViewPager2` to have each fragment have it's own back stack and going back to exact same fragment instead of creating root fragment over and over again. Both solutions require you to have `NavHostFragment` as root of each tab. You can check out the samples [in this repo](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/NavigationComponents-Tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `ViewPager2`. I refer you to two answers for a similar question:

[1- FragmentPagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42781786/2808493)

[2- ViewPager2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63307225/2808493)